# последний элемент в числе python

Tags: python

Допустим есть число 16 или же число 1876(Все это int). Мне нужно получить последнюю цифру данного числа.
 Разбивать на список не хочется т.к. числа могут быть очень большими

Answer (score 4):

https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/operators/modulus.html

```
chislo % 10
```

```js
var chislo = 1876;
var lastDigit = chislo % 10;
console.log(lastDigit);
```

Comment: Но это не python, а JS у вас

Comment: @КонстантинКомиссаров Спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

```py
num = 123456

# очевидный вариант
digit = int(str(num)[-1])
print(digit)

#не такой очевидный вариант
digit = num % 10
print(digit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете получить остаток от деления на 10. Это как раз и будет последняя цифра.

Пример на Ваших числах

```
number = (16 % 10) 
print(number)  # 6

number = (1876 % 10) 
print(number)  # 6
```